# Android: JsonHttpResponseHandler not called

Tags: android, rest

I'm developing a simple Android application as well as a RESTful server to go with it. The application would send a POST request to the server and get a result back.

Here is the android code:
    private void addPoints(String searchString) {

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("category", textCategory.getText());
params.put("points", textPoints.getText());
client.post(QUERY_URL, params,
new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject o) {
        Log.d("omg android", o.toString());

        mDialog.dismiss();
    }        
    // code that handles onFailure()
);
```

When running the application, I can see from wireshark that the request was sent and "Bad Request" (400) was responded. But the response handler was never called. Why?

Comment: 400 != success ... and what is the name of method?

Comment: @Selvin edited. I'm not sure onSuccess equals 200 at this stage.

Comment: Check top level base class/implementation's documentation but not Object of course